# Como editar uma imagem armazenada como BLOB

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Utilizando `Spring MVC`, `thymeleaf` e `mysql`, tenho uma imagem armazenada em banco como BLOB, juntamente com outros atributos e consigo renderizar a imagem na tela normalmente em uma lista.
A partir da lista, consigo acessar um formulário de edição do registro que é preenchido automaticamente com os dados vindos do banco.
O meu problema está no campo BLOB que não é preenchido na tela de edição.
Qual seria a melhor forma de editar essa imagem, juntamente com os demais campos?

Comment: Consegue postar algum trecho de código?

Comment: O ideal é que voce tenha uma tela que possa editar a imagem recuperada no banco, após isso gerar uma nova imagem e gravar novamente a imagem no banco com o tipo blob.

Comment: Então eu deveria renderizar a imagem novamente na tela de edição e colocar um campo opcional pro usuário preencher a imagem. Caso ele preencha eu substituo, caso não preencha eu mantenho a imagem antiga. Isso seria viável?